# Geofencing is not working properly

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, geofencing

In my application I want do geofencing. I have list of locations, for which I am setting geofencing regions. **All location have radius 100m**. Following is the code to set Region:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D cord;
cord.latitude = [location.latitude doubleValue];
cord.longitude = [location.longtitude doubleValue];
CLLocationDistance regionRadius = location.radius;
CLRegion *region  = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:cord radius:regionRadius identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",location.locId]];
[appDelegate.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

My problem is that, its not working properly. For debugging, in didEnterRegion delegate added distance calculation in between current location and region location some times this distance is more then **1500m**.

Following is the code to calculate distance between current location and region location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    CLLocation *loc1 = locationManager.location;
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:region.center.latitude longitude:region.center.longitude];
    double dist = [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2];
}
```

Any idea, why `-locationManager:didEnterRegion:` get triggered such a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

This is a glitch in **iOS Region Monitoring** and I have faced the similar issue with **Geofencing** and I have found a way to solve that problem.

I have posted the question here and I have answered myself, I have a blog post on that as well:-

1. [Region Monitoring Glitch on iOS 7 - Multiple Notifications at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439913/region-monitoring-glitch-on-ios-7-multiple-notifications-at-the-same-time)
2. [iOS Region Monitoring and Location Manager](http://mobileoop.com/ios-region-monitoring-and-location-manager)

Comment: Thanks for answer Ricky. As you suggested to check current location & Region, I did that with distance calculation. Have u found any reason for this wrong behaviour of location manager?

Comment: No problem. You may use **[theRegion containsCoordinate:theLocationCoordinate];** to double confirm if it is really inside the region before triggering the event. I have searched up and down in various websites, I couldn't find anything. I believe it is probably due to bad location with big radius (accuracy) that might happen to a certain countries. I can not confirm on this tough.